# JPQL keep selecting records until condition is not met

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

Struggling with the following scenario:

**Entity**

```
@Table(name = "orders")
public class OrderEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID id;

...

@Column(name = "total_items")
private Integer totalItems;

@Column(name = "create_date")
private LocalDateTime createDate;

}
```

I need to select as many as possible `OrderEntity` objects until the combined **SUM** of `totalItems` is less or equal some integer value (i.e. 500).

So, let's say I have 3 records in the database:

- OrderEntity1 (totalItems = 100)
- OrderEntity2 (totalItems = 200)
- OrderEntity3 (totalItems = 300)

Assuming the threshold for combined `totalItems` value is 500, the query should return `OrderEntity1` and `OrderEntity2`. If the threshold will be decreased to 250, then only `OrderEntity1` should be returned.

Using Java code, I'd do it like this:

```
        List<OrderEntity> orders = orderRepository.findAll();

        int threshold = 500;
        int aggregatedTotalItems = orders.get(0).getTotalItems();

        for (int i = 1; i < orders.size(); i++) {
            // Increment intermediate result
            aggregatedTotalItems  += orders.get(i).getTotalItems();

            // Validate intermediate result
            if (aggregatedTotalItems > threshold) {
                orders = orders.subList(0, i); // limit orders collection from first to (current - 1) order
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with JPQL?

Comment: What RDBMS (and version) are you using?

Comment: Postgres 10.x. But I'd like to keep DB agnostic if possible (JPQL allows it right?)

Comment: seems like you can achieve using `having cause`

Answer (score 2):

This would be quite simple and likely much faster to solve with standard SQL directly:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    t.*,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY o.id) rn,
    count(*) OVER () c
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      o.* 
      SUM(total_items) OVER (ORDER BY o.id) s -- Replace by your order criteria
    FROM orders o
  ) t
  WHERE s < 500
) t
WHERE rn < c;
```

Even MySQL 8 now supports window functions. JPQL doesn't. I sincerely doubt you'll find an elegant and performant solution with JPQL.

Comment: this doesnt answer his question.

Comment: @specializt: How does it not answer the question? SQL queries can be mapped to entities, and I don't see a way to solve this with JPQL. The question was: *"Is it possible to achieve the same with JPQL?"* My answer is "no" and I gave an alternative.

Comment: exactly - thats pretty much the definition of "not answering the question". Im quite sure it might **somehow** be possible, maybe via subqueries with reversed order or something. You not knowing the answer != there is no answer. Always remember that.

Comment: @specializt: Seriously? :) Well, why don't you "answer" the question then, according to your definition? I will be very happy to learn from your answer